# How do you prove axiom 2 when given a vector space of complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that axiom 2 states that (X + Y) + Z = X + (Y + Z) where X,Y, and Z are elements of the vector space and X = (a + bi), Y = (c + di), and Z = (e + fi).

My question is, how do I prove axiom 2 when given this equation?

Answer (score 3):

Collect like terms on the LHS:
$$
((a + bi) + (c + di)) + (e + fi) = (?) + (?)i
$$
Then likewise, collect like terms on the RHS:
$$
(a + bi) + ((c + di) + (e + fi)) = (?) + (?)i
$$
If you get the same result both times, then you've proven that $\mathbb C$ satisfies axiom 2 for being a vector space.